# несколько ссылок на произвольные типы данных в админке

Tags: wordpress

вот код, который добавляет один тип данных и делает для него одну ссылку в админке wordpress

```
                function sliders_ent() {
                $args = array(
                        'label' => 'Слайдеры',
                        'labels' => array(
                                'edit_item' => 'Редактировать',
                                'add_new_item' => 'Добавить новый',
                                'view_item' => 'Показать',
                        ),
                        'singular_label' => 'Передача данных для юридических',
                        'public' => true,
                        'show_ui' => true, // показывать в админке?
                        'has_archive'=>true,
                        '_builtin' => false, // это не встроенный тип данных
                        '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d',
                        'capability_type' => 'post',
                        'hierarchical' => true,
                        'rewrite' => array(
                                        "slug" => '',
                                        'with_front'=>true
                                    ), // формат ссылок
                        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'page-attributes')
                );

                // регистрируем новый тип
                register_post_type( 'sliders-ent' , $args ); // первый параметр - это название нашего нового типа данных

            }

            add_action('init', 'sliders_ent');
```

вот картинка - слева то что есть а справа как я хочу чтоб было[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Решил правда с помощью плагина, так что вопрос еще все равно открыт
только почему так всегда - если хочешь что-то узнать по теме программирования лучше задавать по английски?
типа ok google: wordpress pinned labels in left dashboard